# Добраться до view фрагмента, созданного в xml

Tags: android, kotlin

Я сделал активити, на котором два фрагмента

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/options_layout"
    android:name="com.e.stlpreview.fragments.ActionsFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_actions">

</fragment>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/model_view_layout"
    android:name="com.e.stlpreview.fragments.ModelViewFragment"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/options_layout"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_stlmodel_view">





</fragment>
```

Соответственно создано два класса фрагмента с лайаутами. Пример данного построения взял отсюда https://tutorial.eyehunts.com/android/android-fragment-example-kotlin/. Но возникает вопрос, если я хочу например, установить в imageview второго фрагмента картинку, как это сделать? То есть как при такой конструкции докапаться до view фрагментов?

Comment: Делайте это в коде `ActionsFragment` или `ModelViewFragment` соответственно. Свои вьюхи они сами контролируют

Comment: Тогда как передать им то что нужно нарисовать? Парсинг выполняется в активити. Через onAttach? Ведь получается что фрагменты уже созданы и или его надо менять или как то передать в существующий данные

Comment: Во-первых вот [вопрос на счет получения отображаемого сейчас фрагмента](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9294603/how-do-i-get-the-currently-displayed-fragment). Во-вторых, по идее, активность должна заниматься размещением фрагментов, а всё остальное фрагменты должны делать сами. Во всяком случае, это одна из наиболее простых и распространенных тактик

Comment: Спасибо! Из ссылки попробую выжать. Насчет роли активити, это конечно хорошо, но когда отображение в одном фрагменте зависит от другого приходится выкручиваться

Comment: В таких случаях, когда два фрагмента должны связываться в реальном времени (то есть данные надо передавать сразу), активность должна проложить некий канал связи между фрагментами, а фрагменты должны передавать данные друг другу по этому каналу. Такие каналы данных - тоже ответственность активности, по сути, это элемент размещения фрагментов, просто чуть более сложный

Comment: можно указать tag в разметке и потом искать при помощи FragmentManager.findFragmentByTag. Но так себе решение..

Answer (score 1):

По хорошему ваши фрагменты не должны ничего знать о существовании друг друга. Ваша `Activity` не должна знать о внутренней реализации обоих фрагментов. Я бы предложил вам отказаться от статический фрагментов создаваемый через `<fragment/>`.

Что можно сделать:

1. Создать 2 контейнера (Например `FrameLayout`) для каждого фрагмента. И добавлять их туда динамический. Так вы сможете из `Activity` передавать туда какие-то параметры.
2. Создать *"канал общения"* между фрагментами

   - вы можете создать интерфейс вроде такого:

     ```
     interface FragmentInterractor {

         void setImage(String url);   
     }
     ```
   - реализовать этот интерфейс в вашей `Activity`.
   - во фрагменте в в методе `onAttach()`:

     ```
      @Override
      public void onAttach(Context context) {
          super.onAttach(context);
          if (context instanceOf FragmentInterractor) this.fragmentInterractor = context;
      }
     ```
   - и вызываете `fragmentInterractor.setImage(url);` всякий раз когда вам нужно вызвать из одного фрагмента в другом что-то.
   - и соответственно `Activity` уже передает во второй фрагмент то, что нужно.
3. Как передать из активити во второй фрагмент? Тут есть пару вариантов:

   - создать во фрагменте кастомные методы и хранить в активити экземпляр этого фрагмента для вызова методов. Но мне этот метод не очень нравится, хотя он вроде как вполне простой и легальный.
   - так же работать через интерфейс, только реализовывать его во фрагменте, а в `Activity` экземпляр получать при создании фрагмента.

Comment: Спасибо, похоже вы правы. Дабы работать через таги не со всеми вьюхами получается, но imageview кстати отреагировал. Да также реализовал динамическое создание через контейнер. Попробую чего получится при передаче через интерактор

Comment: Эм, через интерфейс попробовал, результат такой же как и через таги. ImageView срабатывает, а EditText.setText() нет. Почму не могу понять

Comment: Нужно дебажить. Вряд-ли там проблема в в EditText

Comment: Да пробовал. но почему то на самом методе setText проваливается и не вижу никакого лога. TextView тоже самое